# Strange Array Assignment In Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got the following:

```
alert("before: " + JSON.stringify(scenario_data)); // Outputs: {"1":{"amount":{"value":"","inputflag":false},"numberout":{"value":"","inputflag":false},"discount":{"value":"","inputflag":false}},"2":{"amount":{"value":"","inputflag":false},"numberout":{"value":"","inputflag":false},"discount":{"value":"","inputflag":false}}}

scenario_data[1]['amount']['value'] = 1234;

alert("After: " + JSON.stringify(scenario_data)); // Outputs: {"1":{"amount":{"value":1234,"inputflag":true},"numberout":{"value":"","inputflag":false},"discount":{"value":"","inputflag":false}},"2":{"amount":{"value":1234,"inputflag":true},"numberout":{"value":"","inputflag":false},"discount":{"value":"","inputflag":false}}}
```

Why are both `scenario_data[1]['amount']['value']` and `scenario_data[2]['amount']['value']` being set to `1234`?

Comment: 1 and 2 probably point to the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `scenario_data[0]` and `scenario_data[1]` point to the same object. So, when you convert to json, both elements have the same representation. You could verify by checking the value of `scenario_data[0] == scenario_data[1]`.